# My UIView subclass doesn't call drawRect while the user is scrolling an adjacent UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-graphics

I have a subclass of a `UIView` called `UIRefreshView`.  Its sole purpose in life is that, when you pass it an `NSDate*` it displays a rectangle, which gets gradually smaller until the `NSDate*` approaches at which point its width is zero.

It's working well under normal circumstances.  But, when the user holds down their finger on an adjacent `UITableView`, the rectangle stops shrinking while the `UITableView` is scrolling.  Then, it 'jumps' to width that it should be.

What am I doing wrong?

My code (slightly trimmed down) is below.

```
@implementation UIRefreshView

- (void) commonInit {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.8 blue:0.8 alpha:1.0];
    self.color = [UIColor darkGrayColor]; // default
}

- (void) beginAnimatingUntilTime:(NSDate *)targetTime {

    // Store total number of seconds until the rectangle should be gone
    self.refreshInterval = ([targetTime timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]]);

    self.refreshTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0333333  target:self selector:@selector(timerTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void) timerTick:(id)sender {
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGRect foreRectangle = CGRectMake(0, 0, (self.bounds.size.width * [self percentageTimeRemaining]), self.bounds.size.height);

    // Draw BG rectangle
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.backgroundColor.CGColor);
    CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height));
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    //Draw a rectangle
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.color.CGColor);
    CGContextAddRect(context, foreRectangle);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

}

- (double) percentageTimeRemaining {

    NSTimeInterval timeUntilRefresh = ([self.refreshTime timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]]);
    return (timeUntilRefresh / self.refreshInterval);
}
```

Comment: "I have a subclass of a UIView called UIRefreshView" Don't. The `UI` prefix does not belong to you.

Comment: Don't worry, it's not really called that - I've removed a company NS prefix to protect a client's anonymity.

Comment: `NS` also doesn't belong to you.

Comment: No @matt, `NS` is being used to denote a two-letter prefix, it's not the actual one in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

What you're doing wrong is that you're using a timer for animation. You should never do that. Your first choice should be: use actual animation! That way, the animation server takes care of this for you, regardless of what else is happening.

Comment: So the problem is being caused by the use of `NSTimer`?  Please elaborate - I am assuming this is related to the run loop or something similar?

Comment: Exactly so. You're hogging the main run loop while scrolling. But animation server animation takes place on a background thread.

Comment: Just in case I'm wrong and it's the redraw moment that's delayed and not the timer itself, you might try changing `setNeedsDisplay` to telling the view's layer to `displayIfNeeded`, thus forcing a redraw right now. (However, both timer-based animation and relying on a timer to provide an absolute tick are both wrong behaviors in any case.)

Comment: Neither of those changes helped.  The problem was solved by not using NSTimer and, instead, using Autolayout and then animating the constraints instead using `[UIView animateWithDuration...]` calls.